# Checkstyle rule to prevent super keyword

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is there a checkstyle rule that forbids the usage of the super keyword in Java? I searched on Google, but couldn't find anything. Is there an unofficial place to get such specific checkstyle rules?

Comment: Why is `super` evil? If you dont want a subclass to override a function of yours you could use the `final` modifier.

Comment: Final removes the advantages of dynamic dispatch. I want to encourage the use of design patterns (especially the decorator) instead of the super keyword.

Comment: On the other hand it can prevent you from using other patterns, most noticeably Template Method.

Comment: You can do that with abstract classes ;) It may split different patterns to an additional class, but since I work alone on my project, I can always change the rules.

Comment: Erm, how? Calling the constructor of an abstract class, almost certainly requires calling the `suoer` constructor, unless you're not using Inversion of Control, which is another pattern, that is infinitely more useful than Decorator. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkstyle has a "[RegEx](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html)" rule, which can check for lots of different things (we use it to find TODO comments).

By why would you make a rule that essentially prevents you from doing any kind polymorphism?

I'm pretty sure that the train of thought that led you to believe that you need this rule is seriously flawed.

Comment: Think about situations, where super is better to  use than a decorator. I don't want to give a full explanation, as it would be off topic. But I basically made the decision since a professor of my university discourages the use of super.

Comment: I can't think of any situation where using the Decorator Pattern is generally as useful as polymorphism. Furthermore, depending on who your professor is, he might not know what he's talking about. I'm guessing that since he discourages the use of inheritance, he doesn't really understand the concept of OOP, and really has no business teaching a class in Java. In either case, Google Guice uses polymorphism extensively, so if we're doing an appeal to authority, Google trumps Professor. :)

Comment: Well he works on modern programming languages at the KIT in Germany and definetly knows what he is talking about... There are several issues when using super with recursion or simply calling a public method in a class from another public method of the same class. Think for example about extending list to count all insert attempts.

Comment: Please elaborate. I have never experienced this recursion issue, or the other issue that you explain, which seems like you aren't encapsulating your programs properly.